# Case-insensitive search and replace

Tags: java, regex, string, search, replace

I have the following string, how do I search and replace it in Java?

**Before**

```
*animal is a *ANImal and *Bird is a *bIrd.
```

**After search and replace, it shoud be** **animal* = *Dog* and **bird* = *Peacock*

```
Dog is a Dog and Peacock is a Peacock.
```

I have tried replacing the occurances this pattern - **(?i)\\*animal** but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use Pattern.quote()
example: str.replaceAll("(?i)"+Pattern.quote("*animal"), "Dog")

same for "*bird"

Answer (score 0):

```
   public String replaceStrPattern(String str, String pattern, String replaceWith) {

            String newStr = str;
            String nonAlphaNumeric = "[^a-zA-Z0-9]";

    String[] words = str.split(" ");
    for(String word : words) {
               word = word.replaceAll(nonAlphaNumeric, "").trim();
        if(word.equalsIgnoreCase(pattern))
            newStr = newStr.replace(word, replaceWith);
    }

        return newStr;      
}
```

Comment: Yes, that would perhaps solve this specific problem as it is stated, but it would defeat the purpose of trying to find a generic solution to a specific case, which is always preferable over finding a specific solution that will solve just one case. Pick up a good book about Design Patterns and have a read, it'll be well worth it ;-)

Comment: This idea can be generalized if you think about it before giving a pointless comment ... The idea is to split the sentence (how you split it depends on the input and text format) and replace individual words, matching a specific pattern.

Comment: I'm sorry if you thought the comment was pointless - it was meant to be constructive, not condescending. My apologies, perhaps I could have been clearer. The point was that while the approach is valid, a solution which doesn't require hard-coded strings and works generically is going to be helpful to more people. After all, patterns are about not reinventing the wheel and about re-using approaches to problems that can be applied to a range of other, similar ones.

Comment: I agree with that, but the above solution has a pattern itself and it takes exactly 1 min. to abstract the hardcoded part and make it general... I would say it's more of an algorithmic approach rather than a design pattern and you can take multiple directions to solve it - replace, regex, StringUtils ... they are all valid